# How to get URL named parameters inside onBeginRequest?

Tags: php, yii

Is there a way to access the rewritten `$_GET` variables in my `onBeginRequest` event handler when using a parameterized route?

My route is defined as:

```
'<_c:\w+>/<_a:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<_c>/<_a>'
```

And my event handler is:

```
'onBeginRequest' => function($event) {
    /*
    site.com/posts/edit/1 - empty (bad)
    site.com/posts/edit/?id=1 - not empty(good)         
    */
    var_dump($_GET);
    die;
}
```

How do I make sure that $_GET['id'] is defined no matter which of the two URLs above is requested?

I am using Yii version 1.1.13.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do this by having the url manager component parse the current request url:

```
$app = Yii::app();
$app->getUrlManager()->parseUrl($app->getRequest());
```

This will populate `$_GET` and `$_REQUEST` appropriately according to your route. It will also return the active route (controller/action pair), but I am not doing anything with the return value because it looks like you don't need it here.